# 2D Array. Set all values to specific value

Tags: c#, .net

To assign specific value to 1D array I'm using LINQ like so:

```
        int[] nums = new int[20];
        nums = (from i in nums select 1).ToArray<int>();
        nums[0] = 2;
```

There is similar way to do so in 2D ([x,y]) array?
Or short way, without using nested loops?

Comment: your not setting values in an array, your creating a *new* array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ doesn't work particularly well with multi-dimensional arrays.

Jagged arrays aren't too bad:

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                      .Select(x => Enumerable.Repeat('x', 10).ToArray())
                      .ToArray();
```

... but rectangular arrays don't have any specific support. Just use loops.

(Note the use of `Enumerable.Repeat` as a somewhat simpler approach to creating the 1-dimensional array, btw.)

Answer (score 18):

If you really want to avoid nested loops you can use just one loop:

```
int[,] nums = new int[x,y];
for (int i=0;i<x*y;i++) nums[i%x,i/x]=n;
```

You can make it easier by throwing it into some function in a utility class:

```
public static T[,] GetNew2DArray<T>(int x, int y, T initialValue)
{
    T[,] nums = new T[x, y];
    for (int i = 0; i < x * y; i++) nums[i % x, i / x] = initialValue;
    return nums;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int[,] nums = GetNew2DArray(5, 20, 1);
```

Comment: Nice idea but it's seen to me too difficult. I'm searching for simple thing like LINQ.

Comment: The first two (TWO!!) lines of code in this answer solve your problem. I't compact formatting and might look ugly, but you cannot get any simpler, smaller and faster than that.

Comment: would such a single for-loop be faster compared to a nested for-loop ?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this might be cheating because it simply moves the looping code to an extension method, but it does allow you to initialize your 2D array to a single value simply, and in a fashion similar to how you can initialize a 1D array to a single value.

First, as Jon Skeet mentioned, you could clean up your example of initializing a 1D array like this:

```
int [] numbers = Enumerable.Repeat(1,20).ToArray();
```

With my extension method, you will be able to initialize a 2D array like this:

```
public static T[,] To2DArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int rows, int columns)
{
    var matrix = new T[rows, columns];
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        matrix[row, column] = item;
        ++column;
        if (column == columns)
        {
            ++row;
            column = 0;
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: There is no reason for this extension method not to be generic, I updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a new extension method.

```
public static class TwoDArrayExtensions
{
    public static void ClearTo(this int[,] a, int val)
    {
        for (int i=a.GetLowerBound(0); i <= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j=a.GetLowerBound(1); j <= a.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                a[i,j] = val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var nums = new int[10, 10];
nums.ClearTo(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is like so:

```
// Define a little function that just returns an IEnumerable with the given value
static IEnumerable<int> Fill(int value)
{
    while (true) yield return value;
}

// Start with a 1 dimensional array and then for each element create a new array 10 long with the value of 2 in
var ar = new int[20].Select(a => Fill(2).Take(10).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's array inside array. I'm search for way to do this in 2D array [x, y]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple method that loops over all elements and initializes them:

```
public static void Fill2DArray<T>(T[,] arr, T value)
{
    int numRows = arr.GetLength(0);
    int numCols = arr.GetLength(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j)
        {
            arr[i, j] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the same syntax as Array.Fill and will work for an array of any type